WooCommerce Price calculation from price with tax to without tax - decimals
Is it possible to calculate the price using only 2 decimal places? There are a lot of hooks, but other decimal places are still used in the admin area for the line item. Does anyone know a hook or a solution where I can change all price calculations in WooCommerce to 2 decimal places?
The prices without tax contain 4 or 6 decimal places and this must be rounded to 2 decimal places:
What I need
Price without Tax: 2.51 * 7 [QTY] = 17.57
What the shop charges:
Price without Tax: 2.514285 * 7 [QTY] = 17.599995 ~ 17.60
Difference is 0.03
enter image description here
enter image description here
Thanks for help!
I have already used all calculations hooks.

Try to use the following: add_filter('woocommerce_internal_rounding_precision', function($precision){ return 2;}, 9999);… Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme…
